# Number of Decreasing Steps in a Permutation

Tags: probability, permutations, cumulative-distribution-functions

Represent a permutation P of the first N integers in the usual way so, for example,
P = {3 6 8 5 1 2 7 4} means 1 becomes 3, 2 becomes 6, and so on.  One can then
define a sequence Q of (N-1) binary numbers based on the ordering:

```
P = {3<6<8>5>1<2<7>4}   =>   Q = {0 0 1 1 0 0 1}
```

I'm actually only interested in the sum of Q (3 in this example, which is simply the
total number of decreasing steps in the permutation) and its distribution for a
random P.

Has this been studied?

For N=64, what is the probability that this sum is less than 16?

Comment: For smaller $N$, you could easily brute force it. For $N=64$, this seems really hard to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called [Eulerian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796100) [numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693443), sometimes denoted using `langle` and `rangle` $\genfrac\langle\rangle{0pt}{}{n}{k}$, or just $A(n,k)$, where for given $n$, the number of "sum of $Q$" is denoted as $k = 0,1,2,\ldots, n-1$.

Besides many in-site posts (I'm not going to link them), there are numerous expository materials: [OEIS A008292](https://oeis.org/A008292), [OEIS wiki](http://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_numbers,_triangle_of), [some college course stuff](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/wp/eulersumf.pdf), [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianNumber.html), and as always [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number).<sup>Some sources follow the convention of $k$ shifted by one, $k = 1$ to $n$.</sup>

The recurrence is well-known:
$$A(n, k) = (k+1) \cdot A(n-1, k) + (n-k) \cdot A(n-1, k-1) ~,$$

and here's one of the equivalent ways of expressing the general formula:
$$A(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j \binom{n+1}{j} (k+1-j)^n$$
This is essentially your desired probability mass function, off by a multiplicative factor of $n!$.

Below is the table for the first few terms, followed by the "density" plot (probability mass function, PMF) for $n = 10 \sim 20$ on the left and $n = 50 \sim 60$ on the right.
$$k\\n\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline 1 & 1 &  &  &  &  &  \\
{2} & 1 & 1 &  &  &  &  \\
{3} & 1 & {4} & 1 &  &  &  &\\
{4} & 1 & {11} & {11} & 1 &  &  \\
5 & 1 & {26} & {66} & {26} & 1 &  \\
6 & 1 & {57} & {302} & {302} & {57} & 1 \\
7 & 1 & 120 & 1191 & 2416 & 1191 & 120 & 1
\end{array}$$
[image]
It can be shown that the "main chunk" is symmetrically centered at $\lceil (n+1)/2 \rceil$ , with quickly diminishing width as $n$ grows.

The cumulative distribution function (CDF) is $1/n!$ times the [partial row sum](https://oeis.org/A179457), listed in OEIS as $A179457$. The general formula is

$$F(n,k) \equiv \sum_{j=0}^k A(n,j)\\
F(n, k) = \sum_{j = 0}^k (-1)^j (k+1-j)^n {n \choose j} ~,\quad k = 0,1,\ldots, n-1$$

As for the probability of $n = 64$ and $k \leq 15$ "less than $16$", it can be calculated (with some help from the computer) in exact. It's very small anyway. At $n = 64$ the PMF is even more concentrated than the "rightmost" (red) curve in the plot above with $n = 60$.

\begin{align}
\Pr &\equiv F(64, 15) / n! \\
\Pr &=\frac{\scriptsize 3456424774730275582087132747360250797321249625498606659869067546638886\
9017600}{64!} \\
&\approx 2.724 \cdot 10^{-13}\end{align}